# wget cookies login script: same site, HTTP script works, HTTPS doesn't

Tags: django, ssl, cookies, wget

I have the same (Django) website deployed on two hosts; one with SSL and a snakeoil cert, the other just HTTP. I'm trying to script logging in using `wget`. The following script works with the HTTP site but not with the HTTPS.

Note its a Django site. Login requires 2 requests. The first request gets the CSRF token in the login form, the second posts the login cred back - along with the CSRF token:

```
rm ${COOKIE_FILE}
TOKEN=`wget ${LOGIN_URL} -O- --save-cookies ${COOKIE_FILE} --keep-session-cookies \
  --server-response --no-check-certificate \
  | grep csrfmiddlewaretoken | sed -r 's/.*value="(.*)".*/\1/'`
POST="csrfmiddlewaretoken=${TOKEN}&username=${USERNAME}&password=${PASSWORD}"
wget ${LOGIN_URL} -O- --load-cookies ${COOKIE_FILE} --save-cookies ${COOKIE_FILE} \
  --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate --server-response \
  --post-data "$POST" >/dev/null
```

On the SSL site I get this output:

```
--2016-09-13 01:20:38--  https://nowhere.com/accounts/login/
Resolving nowhere.com (nowhere.com)... 10.1.1.123
Connecting to nowhere.com (nowhere.com)|10.1.1.123|:443... connected.
WARNING: The certificate of ‘nowhere.com’ is not trusted.
WARNING: The certificate of ‘nowhere.com’ hasn't got a known issuer.
The certificate's owner does not match hostname ‘nowhere.com’
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 403 FORBIDDEN
  Date: Mon, 12 Sep 2016 15:20:58 GMT
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Content-Type: text/html
2016-09-13 01:20:41 ERROR 403: FORBIDDEN.
```

I have verified I can login to the HTTPS site with the same credentials via a browser. I suspect its something to do with the SSL? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked at what my browser was doing different then added `--header="Referer: ${LOGIN_URL}"` to the second `wget` call and it worked.

Not entirely sure 1. Why Django would be rejecting something without a Referer. I guess it makes sense(?) 2. Why it was working on the HTTP only site. But ... moving on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer man, had same issue and been stuck on it for quite some time